# Does the sum of the reciprocals of all primes of the form $4k+1$ converge?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $S=\{p\in \mathbb{Z}^+ : p\ \text{is prime and}\  p\equiv 1  \mod \ 4\}.$

Is $\displaystyle\sum_{p\in S}\frac{1}{p}$ finite or infinite, and where can I find more information about it?

Comment: The sum of the reciprocals of all primes diverges. Now, primes with residue $1$ or $3$ $mod 4$ are approximately equidistributed in the long run, so it is a very safe bet to say this diverges too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add some references from the literature starting with the [Meissel–Mertens constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant) defined by (the sum is over all the the primes $p$) :
$$M:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{p\le n}\frac 1p-\ln\ln\,n\right)=\gamma+\sum_p\left(\ln\left(1-\frac 1p\right)+\frac 1p\right)$$
(obtained after noticing the precise [divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes))

Concerning the primes modulo $k$ (with $k=4$ in your case) you may start with this article by Steven Finch ["Mertens' Formula"](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/mrtns.pdf) (see page $4$ for $\,p\equiv 1\bmod {4}$) and the relation 
$$M_{4,1}=\frac{\gamma}2-\ln\left(\frac 4{\sqrt{\pi}}K_1\right)+\sum_{p\equiv 1\bmod {4}}\left(\ln\left(1-\frac 1p\right)+\frac 1p\right)$$
with $K_1$ the [Landau-Ramanujan constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Ramanujan_constant) for counting integers of the form $a^2+b^2$ (see too [Finch $2.3$](http://books.google.com/books?id=DL5iVYNoEa0C&pg=PA98) and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-RamanujanConstant.html)).

Further references :

- Languasco and Zaccagnini ["A note on Mertens' formula for arithmetic progressions"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X07000443)
- ["On the constant in the Mertens product for arithmetic progressions. I. Identities"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2807v4)
- ["On the constant in the Mertens product for arithmetic progressions. II. Numerical values"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1665v1)

Answer (score 5):

It's infinite. In fact,

$$\sum_{p \equiv a \bmod b} \frac{1}{p}$$

is infinite for any $a,b$ as long as $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. Dirichlet showed this diverges to prove his theorem that there are infinitely primes in any arithmetic progression $a, a + b, a + 2b, a + 3b, \ldots$ as long as $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

For that matter, we know a bit more. We also know that

$$\sum_{\substack{p \equiv a \bmod b \\ p < X}} \frac {1}{p} \to \frac{1}{\varphi(b)} \log \log X$$

as $X \to \infty$. (So it grows pretty slowly - too slowly to be noticed by most computation).

Answer (score 2):

Dirichlets theorem on arithmetic progressions says there are infinitely many primes in every arithmetic progression $an+b$ where $a$ and $b$ coprime. In particular, there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+1$.

The proof of the theorem makes use of analysis and in fact shows that the sum $\sum_{p = an+b} \frac{1}{p}$ is divergent.

For more information, see here: [Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: How can I make my link work properly?

Comment: I made your link display better. Is that ok?

Comment: Thanks! Now I know how to do it myself next time.